# Duda sobre vistas remotas en MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos esquemas en una misma instancia, para efectos del ejemplo les llamaré **esquema_1** y **esquema_2** el **esquema_1** tiene toda la estructura de catálogos de un sistema ya en producción, el **esquema_2** esta en proceso de diseño.

Por cuestiones de operación los catálogos se mantendrán en el **esquema_1** pero requiero hacer referencia a algunos de ellos (catálogos) en el **esquema_2**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer algo similar a la imagen y como hacerlo, o alguna sugerencia, ya que no se como resolver el problema.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

---

Amplio un poco el contexto, yo quería saber si era posible agregar una "Foreign Key" de una tabla a una vista que se genero en una DB diferente, pero en la misma instancia.
Googleando me di cuenta que lo que pretendo hacer no es posible, ya que las relaciones (FK) solo pueden hacerse entre tablas.

Gracias por la atención.

Comment: Si con esquema te refieres a base de datos, entonces simplemente tienes que especificar la base de datos al referirte a una tabla que no está en la base de datos seleccionada actualmente. Por ejemplo: Esquema_1.Cat_Clientes. Por supuesto, necesitas un usuario que tenga acceso a ambas bases de datos.

Comment: Asi es Jose, en MySql un esquema es una Base de Datos.
Y Googleando obtuve la respuesta a mi duda, definitivamente lo que pretendo hacer no es posible.